# Python: If file does not end with " move up the line below

Tags: python-3.x, csv

So I have a csv file which is created from a program as a report.

This file has lines in it that are not correctly split, all of there lines should end with a ".

What I want to do is if the line does not end with a " the script should move the line from below to the line that is missing the " at the end.

So to give you an example some lines of the file look like this:

```
"2019-08-12","apple", "green
", "dog", "cat", "mouse
", "rabbit"
```

The way I want to look them like is the following:

```
"2019-08-12","apple", "green", "dog", "cat", "mouse", "rabbit"
```

What I tried so far is this:

```
with open(read_path, 'r') as open_file:
    content = open_file.read()

if not content.endswith('"'):
    content.replace('\n', '')

with open(write_path, 'w') as open_file:
    open_file.write(content)
```

But this does not move the line up, I looked at the csv file in Notepad++ and the problem seems to be that on these lines there is not a CRLF line break but instead a LF line break.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried? Also, its easier to write a program for this without considering it to a CSV file.

Comment: yeah you can replace('\n', ' ')

Comment: there sure is, but stackoverflow isnt a give a problem and have someone write a solution type site. we are all happy to help you if you have an issue with code you have written to solve this problem.

Comment: try iterating each line. check if each line ends with "\n. if it doesn't, then, replace \n with "". Hope this will work

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj updated that in the question

Comment: @InAFlash I tried to do that but that does not seem to work it only replaces the LFs in the documents with CRLF line breaks, if I view it in Notepad++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open your file to read and file to write in context and then check if the line ends with `"\n`. If it does then you can just use `rstrip()` to remove any whitespace or new line chars at the end. Then write the line to the output file

```py
with open('test.dat') as data, open('output.dat','w') as output:
    for line in data:
        if not line.endswith('"\n'):
            line = line.rstrip()
        output.write(line)
```

**test.dat**

```
"this", "that", "something"
"2019-08-12","apple", "green
", "dog", "cat", "mouse
", "rabbit"
"hello","world"
```

**output.dat**

```
"this", "that", "something"
"2019-08-12","apple", "green", "dog", "cat", "mouse", "rabbit"
"hello","world"
```

Comment: This fails if the line has open quotes at end. Eg: line 1: `"x","y","`, line 2: `a", "sdf"`

Comment: yes but the OP didnt mention that as an edge case. if the OP confirms that is a use case in the output being split then i will revise my answer. The OP requirement was if the line doesnt end with a `"` then the following line should be appended to it

Answer (score 0):

Given your example:

```
"2019-08-12","apple", "green
", "dog", "cat", "mouse
", "rabbit"
```

It looks like newlines were in the data.  The `csv` module can be used to read and re-write the lines:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv',newline='') as fin:
    with open('output.csv','w',newline='') as fout:
        r = csv.reader(fin,skipinitialspace=True)  # due to spaces after commas
        w = csv.writer(fout,quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL) # to quote every field
        for line in r:
            print(line) # to see what was the original content
            w.writerow([l.rstrip('\r\n') for l in line]) # strip trailing newlines
```

Output:

```
['2019-08-12', 'apple', 'green\r\n', 'dog', 'cat', 'mouse\r\n', 'rabbit']
```

output.csv:

```
"2019-08-12","apple","green","dog","cat","mouse","rabbit"
```

Note that `.rstrip('\r\n')` strips any trailing characters that match the list, so if your line endings are `\r\n`, `\r` or `\n` it will still work.